# Spark Scala Dataframe - replace/join column values with values from another dataframe (but is transposed)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with ~300 columns filled with characters (stored as String):

```
valuesDF:

| FavouriteBeer | FavouriteCheese | ...
|---------------|-----------------|--------
| U             | C               | ...
| U             | E               | ...
| I             | B               | ...
| C             | U               | ...
| ...           | ...             | ...
```

I have a Data Summary, which maps the characters onto their actual meaning. It is in this form:

```
summaryDF:

| Field            | Value | ValueDesc     |
|------------------|-------|---------------|
|  FavouriteBeer   |   U   |  Unknown      |
|  FavouriteBeer   |   C   |  Carlsberg    |
|  FavouriteBeer   |   I   |  InnisAndGunn |
|  FavouriteBeer   |   D   |  DoomBar      |
|  FavouriteCheese |   C   |  Cheddar      |
|  FavouriteCheese |   E   |  Emmental     |
|  FavouriteCheese |   B   |  Brie         |
|  FavouriteCheese |   U   |  Unknown      |
|  ...             |  ...  |    ...        |
```

I want to programmatically replace the character values of each column in `valuesDF` with the Value Descriptions from `summaryDF`. This is the result I'm looking for:

```
finalDF:

| FavouriteBeer | FavouriteCheese | ...
|---------------|-----------------|--------
| Unknown       | Cheddar         | ...
| Unknown       | Emmental        | ...
| InnisAndGunn  | Brie            | ...
| Carlsberg     | Unknown         | ...
| ...           | ...             | ...
```

As there are ~300 columns, I'm not keen to type out `withColumn` methods for each one.

Unfortunately I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to programming for Spark, although I've picked up enough to get by over the last 2 months.

---

What I'm pretty sure I need to do is something along the lines of:

1. `valuesDF.columns.foreach { col => ...... }` to iterate over each column
2. Filter `summaryDF` on `Field` using `col` String value
3. Left join `summaryDF` onto `valuesDF` based on current column
4. `withColumn` to replace the original character code column from `valuesDF` with new description column
5. Assign new DF as a `var`
6. Continue loop

However, trying this gave me Cartesian product error (I made sure to define the join as `"left"`).

I tried and failed to pivot `summaryDF` (as there are no aggregations to do??) then join both dataframes together.

This is the sort of thing I've tried, and always getting a `NullPointerException`. I know this is **really** not the right way to do this, and can see why I'm getting Null Pointer... but I'm really stuck and reverting back to old, silly & bad Python habits in desperation.

```
var valuesDF = sourceDF
// I converted summaryDF to a broadcasted RDD 
// because its small and a "constant" lookup table
summaryBroadcast
 .value
 .foreach{ x =>

   // searchValue = Value (e.g. `U`), 
   // replaceValue = ValueDescription (e.g. `Unknown`), 

   val field = x(0).toString
   val searchValue = x(1).toString
   val replaceValue = x(2).toString

   // error catching as summary data does not exactly mapping onto field names
   // the joys of business people working in Excel...
   try {
     // I'm using regexp_replace because I'm lazy
     valuesDF = valuesDF
       .withColumn( attribute, regexp_replace(col(attribute), searchValue, replaceValue ))
   }
   catch {case _: Exception =>
     null
   }
}
```

Any ideas? Advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we'll need a function that executes a join of `valuesDf` with `summaryDf` by `Value` and the respective pair of `Favourite*` and `Field`:

```
private def joinByColumn(colName: String, sourceDf: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  sourceDf.as("src") // alias it to help selecting appropriate columns in the result
          // the join 
          .join(summaryDf, $"Value" === col(colName) && $"Field" === colName, "left")
          // we do not need the original `Favourite*` column, so drop it
          .drop(colName)
          // select all previous columns, plus the one that contains the match
          .select("src.*", "ValueDesc")
          // rename the resulting column to have the name of the source one
          .withColumnRenamed("ValueDesc", colName)
}
```

Now, to produce the target result we can iterate on the names of the columns to match:

```
val result = Seq("FavouriteBeer", 
                 "FavouriteCheese").foldLeft(valuesDF) { 
                    case(df, colName) => joinByColumn(colName, df) 
                 }

result.show()
+-------------+---------------+
|FavouriteBeer|FavouriteCheese|
+-------------+---------------+
|      Unknown|        Cheddar|
|      Unknown|       Emmental|
| InnisAndGunn|           Brie|
|    Carlsberg|        Unknown|
+-------------+---------------+
```

In case a value from `valuesDf` does not match with anything in `summaryDf`, the resulting cell in this solution will contain `null`. If you want just to replace it with `Unknown` value, instead of `.select` and `.withColumnRenamed` lines above use:

```
.withColumn(colName, when($"ValueDesc".isNotNull, $"ValueDesc").otherwise(lit("Unknown")))
.select("src.*", colName)
```

Comment: Thanks. Guess I can include a match case if pattern to check if colName exists in summaryDF fields (there be typos in Excel/extra columns in valueDF I added). Out of interest, what is foldLeft doing here? One of the scala nuances I’m yet to get my head around.

Comment: You are welcome. 1) as I mentioned, if `colName` does not exist in `summaryDf`, the resulting cell will be `null` (or `Unknown`). Of course, it can be augmented depending on your needs. 2) `foldLeft` here is a form of transformation in a loop: we iterate on column names (*beer, *cheese), taking `valuesDf` as initial value to chain the calls of `joinByColumn` on each iteration, sequentially replacing the df with the result of the call.